# How do I notice time zone changes in Android?

Tags: android, timezone

One can listen for all kind of configuration changes by configuring `android:configChanges` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and act accordingly in the activity's `onConfigrationChanged` method ([Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)).

What I didn't find so far is however a handler that acts on time zone changes. This could for example happen if the user often crosses time zones after a journey and wants to see his application contents in the local time of the country where he's in.

Is the only possibility I have here really to check `TimeZone.getDefault()` regularily myself and adapt my times accordingly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Listen for the broadcasted Intent: `android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED`